# What is a "solving name" as mentioned by William James?

Tags: william-james

> Metaphysics has usually followed a very primitive kind of quest. You
> know how men have always hankered after unlawful magic, and you know
> what a great part in magic words have always played. If you have his
> name, or the formula of incantation that binds him, you can control
> the spirit, genie, afrite, or whatever the power may be. Solomon knew
> the names of all the spirits, and having their names, he held them
> subject to his will. So the universe has always appeared to the
> natural mind as a kind of enigma, of which the key must be sought in
> the shape of some illuminating or power-bringing word or name. That
> word names the universe’s principle, and to possess it is after a
> fashion to possess the universe itself. ‘God’, ‘Matter’, ‘Reason’,
> ‘the Absolute’, ‘Energy’, are so many **solving names**. You can rest when
> you have them. You are at the end of your metaphysical quest.

(emphasis mine)

-Pragmatism A New Name for Some Old Ways of Thinking (1907) (William James)

**My understanding:**

A solving name of an entity is the name of the principle of that entity. So, the solving name of 'God' is the name of the principle of God. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: IMO WJ is describing the ancient magic idea that you can control supernatural powers if you know their "real" (hidden?) names.

Comment: It's not about an arbitrary entity but means metaphysics-solving name, once you possess this name as Solomon's lemegaton you solved all metaphysics problems completely and once for all...